# Executing SqlCommand fails due to "string or binary data would be truncated. the statement has been terminated" error

Tags: c#, gridview, sql-update, devexpress, sql-injection

I am trying to save changes made in a GridView of DevExpress into a table of my DataBase, and I was able to do it with the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[2].ConnectionString))
{
     con.Open();
     GridView gv = sender as GridView;
     using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
     {                    
          cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.tb_Alumno set " + e.Column.FieldName + " = '" + e.Value + "' where pk_alumno = " + gv.GetRowCellValue(gv.FocusedRowHandle, gv.Columns[0]);                    
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
     }
}
```

I have been having this problem since I added parametric command to prevent SQL injection. I have already hardcoded the values for each parameter to encounter the one that provides the error and is the `@val` parameter:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[2].ConnectionString))            
{
    con.Open();
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {                    
         #region Parameters                                        
         //cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.tb_Alumno set " + e.Column.FieldName + " = '" + e.Value + "' where pk_alumno = " + gv.GetRowCellValue(gv.FocusedRowHandle, gv.Columns[0]);
         cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.tb_Alumno set @col = @val where pk_alumno = @id";
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", e.Column.FieldName);                    
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", e.Value);
         //cmd.Parameters["@val"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", gv.GetRowCellValue(gv.FocusedRowHandle, gv.Columns[0]));
         #endregion
         try
         { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
         catch (Exception xe)
         { MessageBox.Show(xe.Message); }                     
    }     
}
```

Aditional information that I can provide:

- The error comes when executing the query
- I am using a gridview from  DevExpress15.1 in the 'CellValueChanged' event
- Data type of the Database is varchar(50) and the parameter is nvarchar
- The error comes when the string exceeds 6 characters (even being "hardcoded")

For example, if I use the following parameter it will throw the same error:
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", "name");`
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", "More than 6 characters");`
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);`
This happens with all fields

If I change the middle line to the following I do not have problems at all
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", "This<7");`

I already tryed to match datatypes as you could see from the commented line, but that throws me no error and does not update the table. I have tested this on other columns too and have the same basic problem.

So my question is, ¿What piece of code should I use to prevent SQL inyection in this particular case?

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all.  I didn't think you could have column names as 'Parameters'.  Can you see what is actually being run at the DB?

Comment: Have you thought about making a stored procedure that calls dynamic sql?

Comment: I have not thought about stored proceadures @dpimente, I just feel easier to do it this way but I do not need to [choose between a shoe and a glass bottle](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925), so it would be great to get the best aproach for this matter. (I will be trying stored proceadures in the near future btw)

Comment: @bowlturner I do not seem to fully understand your question, ¿Can you be a little more specific? (Maybe I miss understand what you said)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the simplest way to solve my issue and was as follows:

I failed to notice that when I created the bound between the datagrid and the database a tableAdapter and dataSet was automatically created. With [this link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1082) as reference I found that adapter had an update method, so I used the information so I simply used this code and it worked like a charm, I also added the line to validate the field wich, to be honest I think is not needed.

```
Validate();    //Or this.Validate();
tb_AlumnoTableAdapter.Update(escuelaDataSet.tb_Alumno);
```

As before, I put this code under the 'CellValueChanged' event but I assume I can atach it to a button to make it a save button. Thanks to everyone for your answers and I hope this helps other like me.

You may also like to read: [How to: Update Data by Using a TableAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a stored procedure that uses dynamic sql. Notice the dynamic sql utilizes sp_executesql which helps prevent sql injection attacks.

The **SQL** code

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_DynamicUpdate]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@col varchar(50) = null,
@val varchar(50) = null,
@id int = 0
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
-- declaring strings
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(1024);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(512)

    SET @SQLString =
    N'Update 
        dbo.tb_Alumno
    set 
        @col_Param = @val_Param
    where 
        pk_alumno = @id_Param'

-- creating the parameters
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@col_Param varchar(50), ';
SET @ParmDefinition = @ParmDefinition + N'@val_Param varchar(50), ';
SET @ParmDefinition = @ParmDefinition + N'@id_Param int ';

-- Executing the stored procedure
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, 
                        @ParmDefinition, 
                        @col_Param = @col, 
                        @val_Param = @val, 
                        @id_Param = @id
END
```

the **C#** code

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[2].ConnectionString))            
{
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SP_DynamicUpdate", con))
    {                    
        #region Parameters                                        
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", e.Column.FieldName);                    
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", e.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", gv.GetRowCellValue(gv.FocusedRowHandle, gv.Columns[0]));
        #endregion
         try
         { 
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
         }
         catch (Exception xe)
         { 
            MessageBox.Show(xe.Message); 
         }                     
     }     
 }
```

This will add more security and allow you to test the stored procedure separately with different parameters. You can even add more checks in the stored procedure call - like checks for column names exist.

In terms of sql injection attacks in the way you're doing it, there's not much more you can do.

Comment: I will mark an answer as correct when I get my problem solved, thanks for the answers and I am trying this method when I can